# Chomsky Normal Form-remove unit production

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

In the step of removing unit productions when converting a grammar to Chomsky normal form, I sometimes found that the variables may end up having the same production bodies. Is this possible? If so, can we consider these variables identical? For example, given:

```
S->aAA|aA|A|a
A->bBBB|bBB|bB|B|b
B->bSSS|bSS|bS|S|b
```

So

```
S-derivable set is {A, B}
A-derivable set is {B, S}
B-derivable set is {S, A}
```

If I add all the non-unit productions from A and B to S, and from B and S to A, and from S and A to B, then the resulting new productions of S, A and B will have exactly the same production bodies.

```
S->aAA|aA|A|bBBB|bBB|bB|bSSS|bSS|bS|a|b
A->same as above
B->same as above
```

Is this correct??

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct. This happened because in your original grammar the non-terminal symbols formed a cycle with the following productions:
$$S\to A$$
$$A\to B$$
$$B\to S$$

So by transitivity all non-terminals can produce the same things.

Comment: So since the body of production are the same for S, A, and B, can these variables be viewed as identical? In other words, can this grammar be simplified?

Comment: Im not familiar to the concept of variables in grammars. I use the terms: terminal symbols$(a,b)$ and non-terminal symbols$(S,A,B)$. So in your grammar described by it's production rules, I can say that the non-terminal symbol $S$ can be replaced with the same things as $A$ or $B$.

Comment: I think variables = non-terminal symbols. So finally, the above 3 productions can be simplified to only one:  S->aSS|aS|S|bSSS|bSS|bS|a|b.      Is this correct?

Comment: You can write infinite amount of grammars that denotes a particular language(for example replacing the non-terminal symbols with others). The Chomsky Normal Form is a good example of rewrite a grammar. The only difference is that CNF has particular rules given by his definition. So yes you can eliminate the non-terminals $B,C$ and still denote the same language changing all $A's$ and $B's$ for $S's$ but it is not necessary and not required for your exercise.